# I need help updating sql entry for a specific user

Tags: php, mysql, sql

So here is what I'm having problems with... I'll explain the table layout.

I have a table called "reg_users"

inside this table i have "email" "uuid" "token" etc....

When the user creates an account, it posts a row to the reg_users table containing email.
However the UUID remains blank, as I would like them to be able to update the UUID field.

Using the script below, I can replace the uuid and update it - but it only works if the uuid field isnt empty.

```
      <?php
require_once 'includes/main.php';

$user = new User();

if(!$user->loggedIn()){
    redirect('index.php');
}


 mysql_connect("sqlhost", "myusername", "password") or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("gl1tchr") or die(mysql_error());
 $uuidold = "$user->uuid";
 // Collects data from "reg_users" table 
 $data = mysql_query("UPDATE `reg_users` SET `uuid` = replace(uuid, '$uuidold', '$newuuid')") 
 or die(mysql_error()); 
 ?>
```

So I need to know how to go into the table "reg_users" and find what row their email is on - and update the field "uuid" on the specific row.

Either that or a script to generate a random number in the "uuid" field for that specific user so my search and replace script will work.

Thank you to anyone who can help me - I'm new to SQL.

Comment: Why are you allowing users to set their own UUID? That is bad practice. UUID should be an auto-incremented field that is not user updateable.

Answer (score 0):

you should be using something called a primary key and autoincrement for your UUID field, and it should not be updateable. This is a unique ID so you can identity every row, and make updates to the row.

Answer (score 0):

While I agree that ID numbers should not be updated after creation, and you should be using an auto-incremented key, if this were not a user ID field and was used to store something else, here's how I would do it:

```
$email = $user->email;  // or whatever you store the email in
$data = $mysql_query("UPDATE `reg_users` SET uuid = '$uuid_new' WHERE `email` = '$email'");
```

This would require knowing the email address of the user, which I think you have from your question.

You may also want to check out PHP's [mysqli extension](https://www.php.net/mysqli), an object-oriented interface for interacting with MySQL databases.